# MapKit viewing angle

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, angle, mapkitannotation

I am working on a program that should detect the pins on the map when the user is approaching to some distance, and the pin has to be in a certain angle of view. I have imported MapKit and added all pins to the annotation.  Now my app is working but takes into account all pins in the map. I need to take into account only the pins that are in a 30 degree of angle. How to do this?

[image: Here is the image how my app appears now]

Comment: what do you mean within 30 degree angle? We need a better explanation and preferably some code

Comment: My program is notify the user if the distance between user and pin is < 800 and if the pin is in the angle of view 30degree. Here is the code that is calculate the distance now i need to add the condition when the user is looking to pin by 30 degree.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking how to change the angle of the view so the pins near the distance you say are visible in a different perspective, if im correct this is the answer:

You need to use the method setCamera on the MKMpaView, this receives an MKMapCamera, you can instantiate a camera like this `let camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2D, fromDistance: CLLocationDistance, pitch: CGFloat, heading: CLLocationDirection)`
where pitch is the angle, all the other parameters are super clear. when you create the camera the you jus call `map.setCamera(camera: camera, animated: true)` and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not written anywhere in the documentation, but it's still being able to calculate the viewing angle of **MKMapCamera** manually. For instance, **SCNCamera** has a property called **fieldOfView**, which is vertical viewing angle and it equals **60 degree**. If **MKMapCamera** had the same property, it would be **30 degree**.